# Wrappers for Auto creation of VM in cloud providers

Tags: docker, cloud, docker-machine, autoscaling

I am looking for a tool which support sufficient providers list (like EC2 , Azure, Google cloud, and private cloud) with the option to create VMs in the cloud.

Have no luck in finding those, seems like I will need to learn lots of APIs to support my project, which doesn't make any sense, it also weird that nobody has already developed something like this, I have found Docker-machine which has lots of drivers for different cloud providers, but it seems like it wasn't support to be the goal of docker-machine, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out packer.io and www.terraform.io

Pakcer helps you build images, and you can deploy them with terraform.
Hope this helps.

Comment: open source is always a better approach :)